# Replacing reinterpret_cast with better alternatives?

Tags: c++, reinterpret-cast

I have a few places in my project where I use `reinterpret_cast` to read/write an unsigned integer from a stream. Consider the following functions:

```
size_t ReadSize(std::stringstream& stream) {
  char buf[sizeof(size_t)];
  stream.read(buf, sizeof(size_t));
  return *(reinterpret_cast<size_t*>(buf));
}

void WriteSize(std::stringstream& stream, size_t n) {
  stream.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&n), sizeof(size_t));
}
```

I started to feel a bit uncomfortable about using reinterpret_cast, even though I've had no problems with it, so I'm wondering, is there a better alternative to this? Assuming I just have 4 bytes in the stream that are supposed to represent this integer.

`static_cast` isn't applicable here either, I think. Any tips?

P.S. I am not currently concerned about portability or other platform-specific problems that may arise from using `reinterpet_cast`. I am writing this for a Windows machine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While the `read` (and `write`) functions are specified to take a `char*`, you don't actually have to pass an array of characters, just cast a pointer to the actual variable right there in the `read` (or `write`) call instead:

```
std::size_t size;
if (stream.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&size), sizeof(size_t)))
    return size;
return 0;  // Or something else on error
```

---

On an unrelated note, I recommend you change the stream parameter to a `std::istream` reference instead, then you can use the function for any input stream.

Comment: Thank you, it looks better. But is there a way to get rid of reinterpret_cast entirely in this case, or is it going to be necessary if I intend to extract an int this way from the stream?

Comment: @InsomniaArray It *is* possible to get rid of the type-casting, by using [*type punning*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_punning) and a `union`.

Comment: @InsomniaArray: reinterpret casts are appropriate at I/O boundaries.

Comment: @KerrekSB Thanks for the reassurance, I just wanted to make sure there isn't much I can do to alleviate the need for it.

Comment: @InsomniaArray: To be clear, that covers only reinterpret casts to pointers to char types. The point is that I/O happens in terms of characters (bytes), and you can build certain objects from their byte object representation by treating the object as a sequence of bytes and writing to those. (You cannot, though, treat any arbitrary sequence of bytes as an object, as you did in your question.)

Comment: @KerrekSB The stringstream content is deciphered data from a file on disk in this case. As it is after deciphering, it's just a stream of bytes. It's supposed to be a certain amount of entries, and the format is such that the amount of entries is written first. What do you mean by saying that "You cannot, though, treat any arbitrary sequence of bytes as an object, as you did in your question"?

Answer (score 2):

So the problem with your code, is that if a little-endian system writes the data, and a big-endian system reads it.

Here, `reinterpret_cast<>` will take the bit image and apply it regardless of any data incompatibilities.

The order of preference is :-

- `const_cast` is used to remove/add only const.
- `dynamic_cast` converts pre-created objects to compatible base/derived.
- `static_cast`  uses compile-time information to perform the same form of conversion as `dynamic_cast`
- `reinterpret_cast`  treats the memory as a union of source and destination.
- C cast `(void*)f;` converts the type using one of `reinterpret_cast` / `static_cast`.

So avoid `C cast`.  This is because you can't really tell what the compiler will choose.
`const_cast` / `dynamic_cast` don't solve your issues.

So the best choice is `reinterpret_cast`.

Comment: reinterpret_cast is best understood as a union, but it is not equivalent. It still has some limitations on applicability, in particular around member function/data pointers. C cast can also cast away const, and IIRC it can also do dynamic_cast. In some cases.

Comment: I do realize there would be a problem with endianess, hence why I specified that these issues weren't a concern to me at the moment. Thanks for your insight, however, it is appreciated.

Comment: I'm confused as to why static_cast is so far down on the list.  I would place it above dynamic_cast in preference... and while const_cast has its uses, I generally find its use to be a code smell since it can lead to undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Since you use a stringstream, you can directly access the string it uses as a buffer:

```
ReadSize(std::stringstream& stream) {
  return *(reinterpret_cast<size_t*>(stream.str().c_str()));
}
```

This saves you some copying.

Anyway, that was not your question. Your code will only work as expected, when your stream provides the data with the same endianes as your machine is working with. You might prefer to handle endianes explicitly:

```
ReadSize(std::istream& stream) {
  char buf[sizeof(size_t)];
  stream.read(buf, sizeof(size_t));
  return (static_case<size_t>(buf[0]) << 24) | 
         (static_case<size_t>(buf[1]) << 16) |
         (static_case<size_t>(buf[2]) << 9) |
         (static_case<size_t>(buf[3]));
}
```

So by the way, you also got rid of the `reinterpret_cast<>`.

Comment: This makes assumptions about the size of size_t. Also your first function may not work depending on the return value type.

Comment: @NeilKirk true, but reading binary data from a stream usually involves a defined stream format, so there already is a size type in the stream and the code reading it should reflect that. The  return value type, BTW, is obvious from the question, though the example code lacks it (and mine as well): `size_t`.

Comment: In the first function, if `buf` has 4 bytes in it but `size_t` is 8 bytes, there will be undefined behavior. Also nothing is obvious in programming. If it returns `const size_t&` then it won't work.

Comment: If the return type is `const size_t&`, the code in the question will not work as well, just like mine. If `buf` has 4 bytes, but `size_t` is 8 bytes, the original code in the question will fail similarly by returning random bits.

Comment: You are correct about the return type - my apologies. On the second point, that is also true, but I'm just concerned the OP didn't consider that possibility of failure.

Comment: I accidentally removed the return type, but yes, it is size_t. I didn't really consider different platforms at this point, so thanks for your insight - I will definitely consider these issues later when porting it over.

Answer (score 1):

Your code makes assumptions about the size of `size_t`, which is not always 4 bytes, even on Windows. What happens if 4 bytes were written to the stream, and you try to read it with code compiled where `sizeof(size_t)` is 8?

You can use the following function to safely and portably (might as well) convert bytes into an integer. It assumes the provided array is large enough, of course.

```
template<class T>
T ComposeBytes(const char *bytes)
{
    T x = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(T); i++)
    {
        x |= (static_cast<unsigned char>(bytes[i]) << (i * CHAR_BIT));
    }
    return x;
}
```

Edit: Fixed an issue where `char` is signed.

Comment: Where does his code make assumptions about `size_t`? He uses sizeof(size_t) everywhere.

Comment: @cdonat What is in the stream? Where does it come from?

Comment: Look at his second function. The Requestor writes, his code does work, but he is uncomfortable with it. So any assumptions he makes hold.

Comment: @cdonat He says he doesn't care about cross-platform, only Windows. He didn't specify only 32-bit Windows. This issue can cause real bugs in real programs costing real $$$, so it's important to mention it.

Comment: @NeilKirk I didn't consider that `size_t` could be 8 bytes in length. Thanks for bringing up this point. Am I right in assuming that `size_t` will be 8 bytes when compiling for 64-bit windows? I guess I'll be better off using something like `uint_32t` instead of `size_t` for better portability.

Comment: @InsomniaArray It should be 8 bytes for 64-bit, but it's best not to assume that in your code either. Using fixed-size types is the way to go in this case.

Comment: @NeilKirk Alright, lesson learned - never assume anything when it comes to size types.